# Why can't I install Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion?

Tags: xcode, software-update, macos

When I try to download the Xcode 4.4 update I'm presented with this error:

```
Xcode can’t be installed on “Mac HD” because the version of OS X is too new.
```

But the change log says that the update is for Lion and Mountain Lion.

Comment: Also deleting Xcode then trying to download from MAS results in the same error.

Comment: Can we assume that `sw_vers` has 10.8 and a build version of 12A269 on your Mac?

Comment: Yes, 12A269. So no MAS update for GM?

Comment: I have the same issue

v4.4 cannot be installed, 12A269

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually clear the store where the App Store saves the downloads before completion:

1. Quit the App Store app
2. Open `Terminal.app` (search with Spotlight)
3. `rm -r /private/var/folders/*/*/*/com.apple.appstore`

   This step is the removal part...
4. Restart the `App store.app`