# Troubles install Xcode 5 on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, xcode, software-update

A few days ago I started to download the new Xcode 5, but I canceled this update at nearly 40%.

Today I'm tried to download the update but it won't download. When I go to Mac Appstore, Updates it says "no updates available". I searched for Xcode in the Mac Appstore and on the Xcode app site there is the update button. But when I click on it Mac Appstore shows me up an dialog telling me

> **You have updates avaiable for other accounts.** To update this application sign in to the account you used to purchase it.

I've never used another account to install Xcode. (Yes, I'm really sure.) I tried with log out and then sign in again in. I also tried the suggestion in this question: [Why can't I install Xcode 4.4 on Mountain Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57518/why-cant-i-install-xcode-4-4-on-mountain-lion)

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. An answer here suggested deleting a receipt directory, but then the 'update' changes to 'install', and I don't think I want an install from scratch. [Being asked to log into a different account on Mac App Store?] (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60018/being-asked-to-log-into-a-different-account-on-mac-app-store)

Comment: Okay. If found a solution, what I did was deleting the old Xcode and installing the new. Maybe not the best way, but that works...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with one of the Xcode 4 versions.  What worked for me was to log in to Apple Developer Network (this will work with your free developer account login), at https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

Although that page says to get the most recent version of Xcode at the App store, there is a link that says **"For past versions of Xcode or additional tools -- view downloads".**

- Click the downloads link
- Unselect all of the checkboxes on the left except **"Developer Tools"**, type **"xcode"** in the box at the top of the left column, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- The top result will be Xcode 5 - click the disclosure triangle to view the download link for it.
- Download the .dmg, double-click on it to mount it and run the installer

Note that the downloads page says that Xcode 5 requires OS X 10.8.4.

As I mentioned, this worked for me when the App Store locked me out with one of the Xcode 4 versions.  If this happened to you, please leave a comment indicating whether this solution works for you.

Comment: Thanks, but of some reasons I have to use the app store.